# How to know the process status of...?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, lbph-algorithm

I have started to train images in open cv using LBPHF model but, I am not able to see the status of training . Can any one help me to find it out?

Comment: You could try using the `tqdm` module with the training step. I have not tried just suggesting

Comment: I want to see the progress while training the data can use sujjest me something which can be done using cv

Comment: It seems there is no way. I tried using the tqdm module for each image but it threw error. I have no clue. I checked the documentation and there is nothing to see the progress